# Is there an active Python-Chat? 

Tags: python, chat, irc

Is there an active Python-Chat?

Comment: kame, the site is about programming, not programming related activities. If a question follows the pattern "XXX *for programmers* ", that this question definitely follows ("Active chat *for Python programmers* "), then it doesn't fit with the intents and purposes of Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are asking for an irc channel where people talk about Python, then try http://www.python.org/community/irc/

Answer (score 0):

[Python Chat Server](http://www.onderstekop.nl/coding/p7_Python_Game_and_Chat_Server/)

[Python Chat Client](http://www.onderstekop.nl/coding/p8_Python_Game_and_Chat_Client/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are looking for a IRC channel? well this is not related to programming so you should not be posting that question here?
any way quakenet has a python channel

Comment: Why this question is not related to programming? :(

Comment: if you are asking for an irc channel well no thats not related to programming, your question was badly formated and it was hard to know what you wanted to know..

Comment: The question was NOT about "an irc channel". The question was about a *programming related* irc channel.

Comment: @porgarmingduod: the site is about *programming*, not *programming related* activities. If the question follows the pattern "XXX *for programmers* ", that this question definitely follows ("Active chat *for Python programmers* "), then it doesn't fit with the intents and purposes of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @voyager: If you think separating *programming* from *programming related activities* makes any sense, then by all means. And maybe you shouldn't ask questions like "How do you arrange several projects in a single SVN server?" Is that programming? No, it isn't. Does it fit here on SO? Yes, it does, as a *programming related activity*.

Comment: @porgarmingduod: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12373/which-types-of-programming-related-questions-are-appropriate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23750/whats-programming-related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40020/what-does-not-programming-related-unequivocally-mean http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16121/why-is-there-a-double-standard-regarding-non-programming-related-questions-at-so http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5304/not-programming-related